# What are the bugs in my code?

Tags: c, compiler-errors

I want to code a simple program in C asking your age and then display the message:
"You are X years old !"

I can't figure out the bugs in the following code:

```
#define <cini.h>
#define MY STRING "You are"

    int main() {
    int age;

    printf("How old are you?\n");
    if(scanf ("%d", age) != 1) {
    printf ("Error message\n");
    exit(1);

    }
    printf ("%s years old!\n", MY STRING, age);
    return 0;
    }
```

Thanks for help and happy Xmas !

Comment: If you can't figure them out, then you need to learn C first.

Comment: @H2CO3 was a little harsh but pretty much right...
The good news is that what you want to do is simple and the errors in the code are fairly easy for experienced programmers to spot and correct.
The bad news is, you probably won't be learning anything simply find-and-replacing; I'd recommend checking out a book or exploring online resources on either C or another programming language (C# and Python are pretty cool and worth looking at!). It's better for you in the long run!
The other good news is that you could learn to code something like this fairly quickly; it's pretty basic. Happy coding!

Answer (score 3):

you missed printing age:

```
printf ("You are %d years old!\n" age);
```

and scan value need `&`

```
if(scanf ("%d", &age) != 1)
```

you defined pre-processor with space, space are not valid here:

```
#define MY_STRING "You are"
```

Answer (score 2):

You missed `&` before `scanf` argument.

```
if(scanf ("%d", &age) != 1)
                ^
                |
              Place & before age
```

Also change your macro `MY STRING` to `MY_STRING`. And also you missed a `%d` specifier in your last `printf`

Use :

```
printf ("%s %d years old!\n", MY_STRING, age);
```

Comment: Not only that, but you can't have spaces in the names of preprocessor directives. "MY STRING" should be "MY_STRING"

Comment: @AlexReinking; Thanks. I missed that.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to rewrite the code and use the debugging tool again to see if I have bugs

Comment: Shouldn't I put #include cini.h for the librairy instead of #define cini.h ?